# ffmpeg fallback second rtmp

Tags: ffmpeg, live, rtmp, wowza

i need to create a system that replace by other stream if the first stream failed.
I am trying to create the command using ffmpeg:

```
./ffmpeg -i rtmp://IP/live/STREAMA -i rtmp://IP/live/STREAMB -filter_complex '[0:0] [0:1] ] [1:2] [2:0] [2:1] [2:2] concat=n=3:v=1:a=2 [v] [a1] [a2]' -map '[v]' -map '[a1]' -map '[a2]' -f flv rtmp://STREAMFINAL
```

I want to to a fallback system if the first stream failed put the second stream without breaks the streamfinal?

Comment: i guess it is not possible with raw ffmpeg, we had to write special app using libav to achieve such goals